# How to make an error message when someone enters an invalid command

Tags: javascript, jquery

This [link](https://thimbleprojects.org/darkdestroyeriii/257297) is to a Thimble project I'm working on using `JS` and `Jquery`. I'm making a text-based game, and I wondered if someone could help me make an error message appear so that when someone types a command that isn't in the functions function it returns an error in my game, and doesn't show one in the console.

Comment: alert(message); ?

Answer (score 2):

With zero code and zero idea how your app actually works, this is the best I can give you.

```
// Create an array of acceptable commands
var commands = [
  "command1",
  "command2",
  "command3"
];

// Get the command typed into the game
var commandTyped = $("#command-line").val();


// Check if the command typed was in the array of acceptable commands
// If not do something
if( $.inArray( commandTyped, commands) == -1 ) {
  alert("That command doesn't exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var commands = [
  "command1",
  "command2",
  "command3"
];

// Get the command typed into the game
var commandTyped = $("#command-line").val();

if (commands.indexOf(commandTyped) === -1) {
    alert('Invalid command!');
}
```

indexOf will ensure browser compatibility. It returns -1 when a list doesn't contain an item.

Alternatively, you could use `includes()`

`if (commands.includes(commandTyped)) { ...`