# How do I make an "Invalid Command" message when someone types an unknown command in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, server, bots, raspberry-pi3, discord.js

I've searched everywhere to find a small piece of code that tells the user that the command they entered does not exist.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990860/how-to-make-an-error-message-when-someone-enters-an-invalid-command), but I don't understand it, can someone explain (or simplify)?

My code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192950/my-discord-js-bot-is-running-online-and-shows-in-console-but-it-wont-respond).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the acceptable commands into an array.

e.g:

```
let userInputCommand = getUserInputCommand();

let validCommands = ["command1", "command2", "command3"];

let isValid = validCommands.includes(userInputCommand);

if(!isValid) {
  return message.channel.send("Please enter a valid command!");
}
```

Use `.includes()` to see if the command exists. (`getUserInputCommand()` is just an example, not referring to your actual code.)

Comment: So, what would the output be if the command is invalid? (Im using the `if(command === ''` thing)

Would I do an "else" statement at the bottom saying something like `if(command === invalidCommand) return message.channel.send("Please enter a valid command!")`

Comment: @AKASGaming I updated my example. To summarize, `isValid` will be true or false depending on if the command is found in the list of valid commands. You can then use `isValid` to decide if you should return your message. In the example I gave, the return message will only be reached if isValid is `false`.